# Which queue to use to paginate queue messages?

Tags: node.js, rabbitmq, queue, messagebroker

Which queue  should I use to be able to fit these 2 requirements?(I use Node.js)

1. Endpoint with pagination that returns items that are currently in queue, but without acknowledgement(it will be used for dashboard to inspect currently items in queue)
2. Remove item from queue by condition, for example id = 5

After some research I found that:

1. RabbitMQ doesn't support pagination and requires to fetch all items from queue in order to inspect queue, the same approach is for delete an item by condition (it may not be performant to loop all items in queue, please correct me if I am wrong),
2. Bull doesn't  support pagination out of box(in docs exists logs only)

Comment: Does it mean a data structure that deletes data that satisfies a condition according to a query? If it is such a data structure, it is not called a queue. [queue](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Queue_(abstract_data_type))

Comment: Does it mean that I should use queue at all?